# Unable to load Database from Asset Folder (Android Studio)

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

quick background - I have no real programming knowledge so think complete beginner!

I used the below guide to load a database from the assets folder and it worked fine
http://www.javahelps.com/2015/04/import-and-use-external-database-in.html.

I now want to adjust this slightly so it loads a different SQLite database which I have created using DB Browser for SQLite  but it is throwing the following error:
Missing databases/Exercisesthree.db file (or .zip, .gz archive) in assets, or target folder not writable

I have placed the new database (Excercisesthree.db.zip) in the same assets folder as the database that works (I have also left the unzipped file there too (Excercisesthree.db).
I altered the DatabaseOpenHelper class to open the Excercisesthree.db instead of the other db (code below) but for some reason it doesnt work. I suspect its something to do with the format of the database as I've hardly changed the code

```
 package com.example.mat.externaldatabasedemo;

/**
 *  Created by Mat on 24-Jan-17.
 */
// http://www.javahelps.com/2015/04/import-and-use-external-database-in.html

import android.content.Context;
import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;

public class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Exercisesthree.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
}
```

Here's a link to the database file:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AupGvbDoJdp9i26l9oO5CcCGf2I0

This is the location of the database files:
C:\Users\Mat\AndroidStudioProjects\ExternalDatabaseDemo\app\src\main\assets\databases

Comment: I doubt this is a Db format problem or else you would see an error when it reads the file. Are you sure the database file is inside "databases" folder? And check if the file names and extensions are correct.

Comment: thanks for the response. I've checked the path, names, extensions etc about a 100 times and cant see any errors in that. I'll load a link to the pic showing the assets folder

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've checked the path, spelling mistakes, extensions etc numerous times and cant spot any errors. here's a link to a pic showing asset folder location and its contents:https://1drv.ms/i/s!AupGvbDoJdp9i2_0DJQt0fxza-5E

Comment: The "progsdb.db.zip" file you can see in the picture is the database that will load. To get it to load that one I just replace "Exercisesthree.db" with "progsdb.db". For some reason I dont have to include the .zip extension. I have also tried changing the code so to Exercisesthree.db.zip but that still doesnt work

Comment: Actually this library does not need you to include the '.zip' file extension. If your db file is 'Exercisesthree.db.zip' your `DATABASE_NAME` would be 'Exercisesthree.db'. Also you don't have to include it as a zip. I guess you can try debugging the library. There is a method called `copyDatabaseFromAssets` set a breakpoint there and work your way through. try changing values while its debugging to see what works.

Comment: HI Naveen, thanks for taking the time to reply. I did try it without a zip extension but it didnt work. Looking at that library I noticed that an older version only allowed you to use a compressed file but this got updated later so I think I must have had an older version maybe. I managed to get it working in the end although never found the root cause of the issue. Thanks for your suggestions though :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've sorted it and confirm it was nothing to do with the Database format. In the end I created a new project and followed the original guide but changed it to the new database.
I think what must of happened is I'd changed some part of the code somewhere along the way and it stopped working. When testing it however it appeared to be working because the original databse had already been loaded onto the emulator and so it masked the fact that the database was no longer loading from the assets folder.

I would have like to have found out exactly what part of the code was missing and stopping it to work to understand a little more and report back but dont think I'll have time